# How to disable Google Chrome search results highlighting?

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

In the last couple days I noticed text being highlighted from search results I click on from Google.

For example, when I click on StackOverflow link from Google search:

[image]

(The yellow was added by Google, not StackOverflow.)

How can I disable this? I don't really like it indicating that some text is more important than other text.

Comment: Same question on [su] -> [How to customize/remove Chrome yellow highlight from search result hash bang](https://superuser.com/q/1492482/152004), [Disable text highlighting in search results (aka: #:~:text=)](https://superuser.com/q/1729662/152004), related [How do text highlighting anchors in URLs work? (ex. #:~:text=highlight%20this)](https://superuser.com/q/1559352/152004)

Answer (score 0):

This is now controlled by a registry key, per https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=ScrollToTextFragmentEnabled

In windows in a powershell admin console:

```
New-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ -Force

New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ -Name ScrollToTextFragmentEnabled -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```